# Weird couldn't match type error

Tags: haskell, types, fold, unfold

I have simple one line function:

```
revRange :: (Char,Char) -> [Char]
revRange t = unfoldr (\b -> if b == (pred (fst t)) then Nothing else Just (b, pred b)) (snd t)
```

It works well:

```
*Main Data.List> revRange ('a', 'f')
"fedcba"
```

Then I want to extract unfoldr lambda as unique function:

```
revRange :: (Char,Char) -> [Char]
revRange t = unfoldr fun t
fun t = (\b -> if b == (pred (fst t)) then Nothing else Just (b, pred b)) (snd t)
```

Now, I have a weird error:

```
Couldn't match type `Char' with `(Char, Char)'
Expected type: (Char, Char) -> Maybe (Char, (Char, Char))
  Actual type: (Char, Char) -> Maybe (Char, Char)
In the first argument of `unfoldr', namely `fun'
In the expression: unfoldr fun t
```

Comment: It looks as if you've included `snd t`, which is the second argument of `unfoldr` in the original version, in `fun`, which is supposed to be only the lambda expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, format your code:

```
revRange :: (Char,Char) -> [Char]
revRange t = unfoldr fun t
fun t = (\b -> if b == (pred (fst t)) 
               then Nothing 
               else Just (b, pred b)) (snd t)
```

Next, double check the type of `unfoldr` using [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=foldr):

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

Next, add a type signature to `fun` so that GHC will tell you what the problem is. According to the type of `unfoldr`, `fun` should have the type:

```
b ~ Char
a ~ Char

fun :: Char -> Maybe (Char, Char)
```

since you are `unfoldr` in the original example with `snd t`.

I usually like to verify small pieces, so we can remove the definition of `foo` and just use the type signature:

```
revRange :: (Char,Char) -> [Char]
revRange t = unfoldr fun t

fun:: Char -> Maybe (Char, Char)
fun b = error ""
```

GHC complains that `t` has type `(Char, Char)` but `fun` expects type `Char`. You've called `unfoldr fun t` instead of `unfoldr fun (snd t)` as in the original example. Move that bit from `fun` into `revRange`:

```
revRange :: (Char,Char) -> [Char]
revRange t = unfoldr fun (snd t)

fun:: Char -> Maybe (Char, Char)
fun b = error ""
```

Next, add in the definition of `fun` again. We can remove the lambda and put `b` as a normal argument to `fun`:

```
fun:: Char -> Maybe (Char, Char)
fun t b = if b == (pred (fst t)) 
          then Nothing 
          else Just (b, pred b)
```

Immediately we see another glaring problems: `fun` takes *two* arguments but the signature says it should only take one!

Since `t` is a constant in the original lambda, we can solve this problem by partially applying `fun` in `revRange`, so the final answer is:

```
revRange :: (Char,Char) -> [Char]
revRange t = unfoldr (fun t) (snd t)

fun:: (Char, Char) -> Char -> Maybe (Char, Char)
fun t b = if b == (pred (fst t)) 
          then Nothing 
          else Just (b, pred b)
```

---

To address your comment, you'd like to write

```
revRange :: (Char,Char) -> [Char]
revRange = unfoldr fun2
```

Using the same approach as above, in the signature of `unfoldr` we need `b ~ (Char,Char)` and `a ~ Char`. So we'd like `fun2` to have the type

```
fun2 :: ((Char,Char) -> Maybe (Char, (Char, Char)))
```

I'll leave the definition of `fun2` as an exercise. As a hint, I suggest adopting the convention that the first part of the pair is constant and holds `fst t`.

Comment: I have one more question. Is it possible to move `(snd t)` to `fun`? I want to see first line as `revRange = unfoldr`.